# Python markov chain, user input string to transition matrix

Tags: python, weather, markov-chains

I'm making a weather prediction program in Python using a Markov chain. The programs asks the user for input on past days' weather and predicts the next seven days.

I was wondering how I can change my transition matrix so it uses the percentages of how often the specified pair happens i.e. 'DD' 'DR' 'RR' 'RD' rather than default probability as I have shown below.

```
#Possible sequences of events
transitionName = [["DD","DR"],["RR","RD"]]

pastweather = input("Enter a string of D's and R's to represent dry/rainy days: ")

#transition matrix
transitionMatrix = [[0.8,0.2],[0.4,0.6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if a Markov chain is the most suitable tool here. In general, a Markov model has no memory, i.e. the next transition depends only on the current state (dry or rainy) and you want to do a seven day forecast...

However, concerning your questions about the calculation of the transition matrix I would suggest the following approach:

Let's consider a user's input like : DDDRDD

- Overall there are five transitions.
- There are three transitions D->D
- There is one transition D->R
- There is one transition R->D

Prerequisites:

- All transitions starting with D have to sum up to 1.
- All transitions staring with R have to sum up to 1.

Therefore, the probability for D->D according to the input string would be 3/4. The probability for D->R would be 1/4.
Probability R->D is 1 and R->R is 0 - as there was no transition in the input string from R -> R.